# Image Recognition - Find Distance from Object to Surface

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, photogrammetry

Given [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKCi9.jpg), how would I determine how high above the street the top of the arch is?  Assume I know how wide one of the arches is.

My first thought was to draw an orthogonal line straight down from the top of the arch to the street and calculate the length of the line based on the width of the arch.  However, I don't know where to start in determining which point on the road is directly underneath the top of the arch.

Edit:  Maybe width isn't the best word.  I mean how tall the top section of the arch is from top to bottom. That is, if you take the chunk out of the arch [indicated here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZJfA.jpg), we would know the dimensions of said chunk.

Comment: I doubt that this information can be extracted from the picture. When you say that you know the width, what do you mean ? Where precisely is it measured ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear.  I edited in the information into my original post.

Comment: Hello I think the word you are looking for is **height** not width. In any case you cannot directly determine the height without knowing the distance of the arch from the camera. If the arch is close it will appear taller in the image (more pixels) if it is far away it will be shorter (less pixels). But we know in both cases, the arch never actually changes. It's always `X`meters tall. This might be useful, it uses a fixed size object (at different locations) to help "calibrate" the camera http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/

Comment: @Upstreamer: still completely unclear (actually even less clear than before). What "chunk" ? A dimension must be between two points, not at the tip of a single arrow.

Comment: @andrew Yes, we can assume we know the distance from the camera to the arch.  And thanks for the link, I'll check it out.